# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS desktop doesn't show trash icon

Tags: icons, trash, desktop-icons

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.

Since 19.10, I cannot see the trash icon on the desktop.

Is there a way to recover this icon?

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it's wrong for Ubuntu Studio. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks a lot for your interesting!!!